# Pinch gesture will not work

Tags: swift

I have some image with `Pan` and `Tap` gesture recognizers which works great.

I try to also add pinch gesture, but the delegate will not even fired  :

```
 func addPinchTo(image:UIImageView)
    {
        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector( self.Pscale(gesture:) ))
        let rotationGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector( self.ProtateArt(gesture:) ))
        image.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
        image.addGestureRecognizer(rotationGesture)
        image.isUserInteractionEnabled =  true


    }


func Pscale(gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

        print("D") //not print
   }

  func ProtateArt(gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {

        print("aD") //not print
}
```

Comment: You code looks fine. Have you checked if the class where this method is, is not getting deinitalized after  the method is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code worked great, just not on the mac, even with the trackpad that let you pinch you cant do it on the mac, only on the iPhone.

Comment: Yes. There is no need to return anything from the method. Note that in your question you are using UIImageView and UIPinchGestureRecognizer which are only available in UIKit (iOS) not macOS

Comment: If you would like to monitor pinch in your macOS trackpad you need to override your view controllers magnify method    `override func magnify(with event: NSEvent) {
        print(String(format: "%.2f%%", event.magnification))
    }`. to monitor rotation you need to override rotation method `override func rotate(with event: NSEvent) {
        print(event.rotation)
    }`

Answer (score 2):

```
func addPinchTo(image:UIImageView) -> UIImageView
    {
        let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector( self.Pscale(gesture:) ))
        let rotationGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector( self.ProtateArt(gesture:) ))
        image.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
        image.addGestureRecognizer(rotationGesture)
        image.isUserInteractionEnabled =  true

        return image
    }


func Pscale(gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

        print("D") //not print
   }

func ProtateArt(gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {

        print("aD") //not print
}
```

or thanks to @Leo Dabus, using `@objc` methods will work fine also.

```
@objc func pinch(gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    print("hit from pinch function")
}

@objc func rotation(gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
   print("hit from rotation function")
}
```

and to make it work, your code should look something like this

```
    func addPinchTo(image: UIImageView) {
    let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pinch))
    let rotationGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rotation))
    image.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
    image.addGestureRecognizer(rotationGesture)
    image.isUserInteractionEnabled =  true
}
```

Try this, it should work

Good luck!

Comment: This is wrong. You don't need to return anything. Btw It would be much easier to just add `inout` keyword to it but definitely it is not needed here.

Comment: Hi leo, its been a few months i've used it and it works fine, just sharing my code, ps: sorry, if you want me to delete it, i'll do

Comment: This is up to you. I won't vote it down but someone else might do it.

Comment: i mean it works okay, and two upvotes? you may be right

Comment: Note that people who upvoted that have no idea what they did :)

Comment: @LeoDabus, i wouldn't mind losing my points but i am new to stackoverflow trying to get attention, i've updated it using your code if its cool

Answer (score 1):

The problem it is that you probably never called the method that adds the gesture recognizer to your image view. And if you are coding in Swift 4 make sure to add @objc to your methods. Btw it is Swift convention to name your methods starting with a lowercase letter:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    addPinchTo(image: imageView)
}

func addPinchTo(image: UIImageView) {
    let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pinch))
    let rotationGesture = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rotation))
    image.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)
    image.addGestureRecognizer(rotationGesture)
    image.isUserInteractionEnabled =  true
}

@objc func pinch(gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    print(#function)
}

@objc func rotation(gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    print(#function)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one gesture recognizer you may implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` and return `true` for this method

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return Bool
}
```

> This method asks the delegate if two gesture recognizers should be
>   allowed to recognize gestures simultaneously.

For example :

```
    let gifImageView = UIImageView()
    gifImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
    gifImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    gifImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    gifImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    gifImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        gifImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBarView.bottomAnchor, constant: 16),
        gifImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
        gifImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
        gifImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: collectionView.topAnchor, constant: -16)
    ])

    let rotationGestureRecognizer = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleRotate(_:)))
    rotationGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    gifImageView.addGestureRecognizer(rotationGestureRecognizer)

    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(_:)))
    panGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    gifImageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)

    let pincGestureRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinch(_:)))
    pincGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    gifImageView.addGestureRecognizer(pincGestureRecognizer)
    view.addSubview(gifImageView)
```

And than your handling functions :

```
 @objc func handleRotate(_ gestureRecognizer : UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
        gifImageView.transform = gifImageView.transform.rotated(by: gestureRecognizer.rotation)
        gestureRecognizer.rotation = 0
    }
}

@objc func handlePan(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        gifImageView.center = CGPoint(x: gifImageView.center.x + translation.x, y: gifImageView.center.y + translation.y)
        gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
    }
}

@objc func handlePinch(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began || gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
        gifImageView.transform = gifImageView.transform.scaledBy(x: gestureRecognizer.scale, y: gestureRecognizer.scale)
        gestureRecognizer.scale = 1.0
    }
}

//Finally implement gesture recognizer delegate method 

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```